# How to expose variable in Python module?

Tags: python

What is the best way to expose a variable from a module?

```
import otherDBInterface as odbi

def create(host):
    global connection
    global cursor
    connection = odbi.connect(host)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    ...
```

I want to expose the `cursor` variable in the module so I can do something like `mydb.cursor.execute("select * from foo;")`.  I thought using the `global` keyword would do this but no such luck.  `cursor` is an object so I am not sure how I would declare it so that it would be exposed.

Comment: That should do it, but obviously you'll need to call the `create` function before `cursor` will exist.  Can you show the code where you try to import/use the `cursor` object?

Comment: Is `mydb` is module name?

Comment: Yes, in this example, `mydb` is the module name.

Comment: BrenBarm, I figured it out.  I have two "constructors" in this module and one of them wasn't setting `cursor`.  I changed it to do that and now it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap your connection information in a class

```
class Database:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        if kwargs.get("connection") is not None:

            self.connection = kwargs["connection"]

        elif kwargs.get("host") is not None:

            self.connection = odbi.connect(host)
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

mydb = Database(host="localhost")

results = mydb.cursor.execute("select * from foo")

#or use it with a connection

mydb = Database(connection="localhost")

results = mydb.cursor.execute("select * from foo")
```

Comment: +1 to counter the unexplained anonymous downvote.  Encapsulating in an object is vastly better than a global variable, and usually more correct to boot.

Comment: Is there a way to have two "constructors" in a Python class?  I need a `connect()` constructor to connect to an existing database and a `create()` constructor to build a database from scratch.

Comment: What you are asking for is called method overloading and languages like Java have that, but not Python. In Python you would use dynamic arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Any variable created on a module level is "exposed" by default.

Hence, a module like this will have three exposed variables:

```
configpath = '$HOME/.config'

class Configuration(object):

    def __init__(self, configpath):
        self.configfile = open(configpath, 'rb')

config = Configuration(configpath)
```

The variables are `configpath`, `Configuration` and `config`. All of these are importable from other modules. You can also access `config`s `configfile` as `config.configfile`.

You can also have configfile accessible globally this way:

```
configpath = '$HOME/.config'
configfile = None

class Configuration(object):

    def __init__(self, configpath):
        global configfile
        configfile = open(configpath, 'rb')

config = Configuration(configpath)
```

But there are various tricky problems with this, as if you get a handle on `configfile` from another module and it then gets replaced from within `Configuration` your original handle will not change. Therefore this only works with mutable objects.

In the above example that means that using `configfile` as a global in this way will not be very useful. However, using `config` like that could work well.